# Text to float or decimal conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need a help in SQL query .

i have a table like

**A | B   |  C**
 1 | 1.3 | p
 2 | 2.6 | c

fields (A- type int) (B--type(text)) (C-Type(nvarchar))

i need to multiply (some value with (B type(text))
example
(1.3 X b)) as x  is it Possible .

please let me know

Comment: The true fix for this is to fix your table design. Not only is text a poor choice to store numbers you expect to do calulations on, it is deprecated and will NOT be in the next version of SQL Server. This is a "must fix as soon as possible" design issue.

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) :

Try something like this :

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(10,5),(CAST(B AS varchar(10)))) * MyValue 
AS MyMultipliedValue FROM TABLE
```

Comment: hi thanks for ur response but it show 
Explicit conversion from data type text to decimal is not allowed. this error

Comment: @raja : OK ! Checked the Conversion Table in the article I mentioned, and text to decimal is indeed not allowed. I edit my post.

Comment: @raja : firstly you cast your text as a varchar, then you convert it to decimal. In fact, the convert may be not need as it may be implicit.

Comment: @raja : if it helped you, don't forget to validate my answer ;)